# After maven build some class files are not created in jars

Tags: java, xml, maven, jar, pom.xml

After maven build some java files in which i have written code, are not created in jars. Why is this happening? I am just started using maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easy to answer without your pom.xml but be sure about following items

1. Check if any excluded class in pom config
2. Be sure about all classes inside src/main/java or not
3. run mvn clean install

And if you share pom.xml here we can answer easly.

Comment: Thank You! It work